# Flavors vs. Libraries?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I just finished watching [Xavier Ducrohet presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0) about gradle, and I am about to start using flavors.  I want to understand what are their big advantage over libraries?

I know that android library can have it's own manifest / resources and of course sources, and so does flavors. But what else is there? Why should I use them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flavors and libraries aren't really comparable.

A library is typically a discrete piece of functionality that you can reuse across multiple projects. It might provide a piece of functionality that you use frequently or it might provide a custom View that you find yourself using in a lot of applications.

Product flavors are slightly different versions of the same application. The most common example is a paid vs. free app- with product flavors you can have a single codebase that generates both versions. Another more simplified example would be an app that is available in two colors- you might have a red product flavor and a blue product flavor. In this case the only difference might be a single color string in your resources.

Where I think the confusion is coming from is that you can use a library to accomplish the goals of the product flavor system. That is, you can take your common functionality and place it in a library project that you include in each of the versions of your application. This is a messy way to accomplish the goal of having two apps with only minor variation between them, and if this is your goal, you should use product flavors instead.

From the [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors):

> If the answer to “Is this the same application?” is yes, then this is probably the way to go over Library Projects.